# What's the expected result for an IN query with a sort order on another property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

According to the docs...

> The IN operator also performs multiple queries, one for each item in
>   the specified list, with all other filters the same and the IN filter
>   replaced with an equality (==) filter. **The results are merged, in the
>   order of the items in the list**.

What happens if there is a sort order on another property?

```
query = Post.query(Post.tags.IN(['python', 'ruby', 'php'])).order(-Post.views)
results = query.fetch(20)
```

Will the results be sorted according to the number of views in descending order?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you not just test it? Asking the question had to take longer.

Comment: I think I wanted to get an "official" expected result for this kind of query. I couldn't find the answer in the docs. I knew I could have tested it and found out what the result would be, but that wasn't why I asked my question. I'm asking what's the defined expected result for this kind of query, because I've experienced doing undocumented things on GAE that did what I wanted it to do, only to be advised later on not to do it, because it's "undefined". So my question is, what's the defined expected result for this query? I would greatly appreciate it if I could get an official answer. Thanks!

Comment: It is ordered by the `order` clause. All queries have a natural order; the purpose of `order` is to override them. I can't test this but it's the only logical answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, results will be ordered by the order you specify. The SDK wouldn't let you execute a query if it wouldn't give you the results you requested.